# How does w3schools quiz timer work and how to create one like it?

Tags: javascript, function, timer, alert

I'm a JavaScript programmer who is planning on building a timer... this timer requires to only stop when a user has finished a certain process.

I have built a basic timer which works just fine but it freezes for the function `javascript: alert("stop");`. The quote stop is not that important but somehow the timer stops when i enter this script in the address bar of my browser and when I click okay in the dialog box the timer proceeds from where it stopped.

I've been told that this cannot be prevented but when I visited w3schools quiz page and took a quiz i tried this alert function on their website and reloaded the page the timer displays the correct duration of time I just want to know whether any of you are aware of the technique that w3schools uses for timer could share it with me so that I can use it for my timer.

I just want to know whether this timer works externally whether the script is in the page that the timer is displayed or whether the timer script is kept in an external file and I have noticed that the timer at w3schools does not display the duration on a real-time display but only shows the correct time when I go to the next answer or refresh the page so if you'll could provide a solution for this to display it in a real-time display without having to refresh the page I would love that.

Comment: Hello.. Can you please break that wall in some bricks?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! A couple of notes: **Please post the code you have**, either here in a simplified version (<20 lines), or on your own site, or on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com). Also, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Why do you care how your website reacts if the user executes custom JavaScript? One final note: Try shorter (and punctuated) sentences, and separating your question into paragraphs. I've tried to do that, but I'm sure you can structure it even better.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look with a tool like Chrome's Developer Tools, you'll see that the starting time is sent along each time you navigate to the next question, using POST:

```
Form Data
    starttime: 1/6/2012 7:02:31 AM
    answers: 00000000000000000000
    qnumber: 2
```

The server interprets this data and most probably does something like `(now - starttime).toMinutes()` (pseudocode) to display the time spent. This also works when reloading the page, because time doesn't stop - `(now - starttime)` will obviously always give the correct result when the page is being built on the server.

It doesn't use JavaScript for this, so alerts don't pause anything - it's just a simple calculation on each page load.

Comment: okay thanks... i get it now so mostly for my timer the correct time is way more important than real-time display so i think i'll develop a code that cannot be frozen so i am planning on creating a timer that calculates the time taken since initialization for my script like the one at w3schools so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine if it is not updating in real time, then it is probably not a timer, but more likely just a storage of the time you started, and then some calculations every so often of the time elapsed.